# If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u)>0$ for all $u\in S^{m-1}$, then $\exists a$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)=0$ for all $v$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $S^{m-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^m$ centered at origin and $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function that has all directional derivatives at any point of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that if, for all $u\in S^{m-1}$, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(u)>0$$ then there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that, for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a)=0$$

Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Makes sense now?

Comment: The sentence "for all $v\in{\mathbb R}^m$,
$${\partial f\over\partial v}(a)=0\ {\rm "}$$
makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: What do you know about a continuous function on the unit ball ($S^{m-1}$ together with its interior in $\mathbb R^m$)?

Not-necessarily-relevant question: Must $f$ actually be differentiable with these hypotheses?

Comment: I know that a continuous function attains maximum and minimum in the unit ball (because the unit ball is a compact set). Is this the answer that you want?

Comment: Yes. Now proceed! P.S. Out of curiosity, what's your book's definition of directional derivative? Is it one- or two-sided?

Comment: In my book, the directional derivative of $f$ at point $a$ is the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t}$ if this limit exists.

Comment: In your second question, you are saying that some hypothesis is not necessary? Which one?

Comment: No, no. I'm just remarking that $f$ can have all directional derivatives without being differentiable. However, the most obvious continuous and non-differentiable function that meets the hypotheses of your problem will fail to have directional derivatives at the minimum point.